# From azure sql Database to snowflake

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, data-warehouse

I am thinking about using Snowflake as data warehouse. My databases are in Azure SQl Database and I would like to know what tools I need for etl my data from Azure SQL Database to Snowflake.
I think Snowpark could work for data transformations, but I wonder what other code tool could I use.
Also, I wonder if I use azure blob storage as staging area or snowflake has its own.
Thanks

Comment: _I am thinking about using Snowflake as data warehouse_ any sepcific reason you want to change platforms? It's not a task to take on light heartedly

Comment: Please review the following reference as a starting point: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6508/copy-data-from-and-to-snowflake-with-azure-data-factory/

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately this question is off-topic, as you're asking for tool/product/service recommendations. It's also an opinion-based question, and there's really no way to answer this objectively. Plus, there's no specific programming question here.